# How to find CDF of marginal distribution?

Tags: integral

CDF of marginal distribution:

I am trying to find Cumulative Distribution Function of Marginal PDF. I tried to solve it. But the answers were different that that expected one. So it would be helpful if someone can point out my mistake.

I have added the image of the steps below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpFoN.jpg)

Comment: Stckoverflow is for coding questions. Ask that on cross-validated or stack exchange mathematics